# Android - How to stop camera intent from saving on the phone

Tags: android

On my app I'm using the mobile phones camera and saving the image on the sd card. The issue is that the picture is also being saved on the mobile phones memory. Is there any way I cant stop this?

This is the code to start the camera intent:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

This is the code to save the image to the sd card:

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/wardrobe_app");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
    file_path = myDir.toString();
    img_path = file_path + "/" + fname;
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(addClothing.this,
            img_path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
```

And this is code to set an ImageView as the picture taken:

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv1.setImageBitmap(photo);
        SaveImage(photo);
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I believe this is impossible without root, at least with intents. Your code isn't the issue; it's due to how the camera app works - when the user takes a picture, the camera app itself will save that picture to the device memory and return a Bitmap. So this is entirely out of your control unless you have root and can use reflection to modify the camera app to prevent saving.

The other option is to use the Camera API in your app directly.