# Camera Intent From Developer.Android Crashes After Multiple Cancels

Tags: android

So, I've come to find that the method of starting a camera intent provided by:
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Will eventually fail if you take a photo, and then hit cancel multiple times. I've tried it on other apps than the one I'm building and sure enough, the application also crashes after a few photos taken and cancelled. I assume this is because each photo remains in memory until returning to another activity. Combine that with the fact that hitting the cancel button does not produce an activity result in which to handle the previously taken picture, it seems like a limitation of the camera application itself.

My question is: Is there a way of getting around this while still using the built in camera application via intent? Is there a method I can call to keep it from caching the canceled images into memory?

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like a limitation of the camera application itself

Please bear in mind that there are hundreds of pre-installed camera apps (across thousands of device models and well over a billion active Android users), and countless more such apps on the Play Store and elsewhere, that might respond to `ACTION_CAPTURE_IMAGE`. While many have bugs, the bugs vary, and so the behavior that you are seeing is tied to that specific camera app that you happen to be invoking.

> I assume this is because each photo remains in memory until returning to another activity

I certainly would not assume this, but if the other app is what is crashing, there is little that you or I can do about it.

> Is there a way of getting around this while still using the built in camera application via intent?

You are not in position to fix all the bugs across all the camera apps across all the devices in use.

> Is there a method I can call to keep it from caching the canceled images into memory?

There is nothing in the Android SDK for you to tell another app that it has a bug and should stop breaking.

Answer (score 0):

According to Eric Ahn ([Android - How to stop camera intent from saving on the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843835/android-how-to-stop-camera-intent-from-saving-on-the-phone)) the only way around this is to create your own camera activity and handle the callbacks yourself via the camera's API. I'll probably look into it some more later, but I suspect Eric is right.